# How to test checked radio button from views.py?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django project where my home page contains radio button which gives me the opprtunity to go to to another application or to show a message .I think that my test of button checked is not written correctly .
log/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required,user_passes_test
from aps import views
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required()
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request,"home.html") 
        if ('choix1').checked  in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse("hedha lmail")
        elif 'choix2'  in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse("hedha ltemps")
        elif 'choix3'  in request.POST:
            return views.index(request)
        else :
            return HttpResponse("You have not chosenn ay choice")
    else:
        return views.index(request)
```

home.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>You are on your account</p>

        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            
<FORM>
<p>you have the opprtunity to : </P>
<INPUT type= "radio" name="choix1" id="choix1" value="mail"> change mail sender
<INPUT type= "radio" name="choix2" id="choix2" value="temps"> change frequency of getting temperqture sensor's value
<INPUT type= "radio" name="choix3" id="choix3" value="graph"> show graph  <br>
<INPUT type= "submit" value="ok"> 
</FORM>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove

```
return render(request,"home.html")
```

because your app doesn't reach the the `if` check.

Also, add POST method to your html form:

```
<form method="POST">
```

To see if a radio is selected:

```
if 'choix1' in request.POST:
    ...
```

Comment: I changed it it says Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /log/ and home .html I can't remove it because the superuser should access to the home firstly

Comment: remove `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` from your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py` file

Comment: thank you but even when i removed it it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required()
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request,"home.html")           #this line I am talking about
        if ('choix1').checked  in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse("hedha lmail")
        elif 'choix2'  in request.POST:
            return HttpResponse("hedha ltemps")
        elif 'choix3'  in request.POST:
            return views.index(request)
        else :
            return HttpResponse("You have not chosenn ay choice")
    else:
        return views.index(request)
```

In line number 4 in above method you are returning your method before any conditions could be checked.

Comment: the super user has to choose a button in home.html  and the checked one will gives him the opportunity to access to another application or to show message